# pass repository to class from Command Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a code in Symfony 3.2, where I am trying to pass repository from Commmand class to my custom class, where I am running the websockets

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Command;

use MyBundle\Server\Notification;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    /**
     * Configure a new Command Line
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('Project:notification:server')
            ->setDescription('Start the notification server.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('My.repository.car');‏

        $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Notification($this->getContainer(),$em)
            )
        ), 8080);

        $server->run();
    }

}
```

for All my db queries I am using repositories and there is no Entity. I have done this before, and it was working fine.
But now when I run command from terminal I am getting this error

> Parse error: parse error in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lavtaxi/src/MyBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php
>   on line 28

on line 28 there is

> "$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer( "  part

this is my services.yml

```
services:
    My.repository.car:
        class: MyBundle\Repository\CarRepository
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

and this is Notification.php where I am trying to get data and send via sockets

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Server;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Notification implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $connections = array();
    private $users = array();
    protected $container;
    private $drivers = array();
    private $repository = null;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $em;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->users = [];
        $this->drivers = [];
    }

    /**
     * A new websocket connection
     *
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->connections[] = $conn;
        $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
        $this->drivers = $this->repository->getCarsData();
        $conn->send('..:: Hello from the Notification Center ::..');
        $conn->send(json_encode($this->drivers));
        echo "New connection \n";
        }
}
```

Error is disappears when I remove the repository calling part above, so I know that problem is not on IoServer

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in PhpStorm, and it seems that you have a very strange character after `->get('My.repository.car');`. Wrong line break ?

Comment: Thanks there really was something wrong, and some strange thing, I have cleared everything after it, it works now.

Comment: That is not how you create a doctrine repository.  You need to go through the EntityManager::getRepository(EntityClass) for it to work using a factory method in your service definition.  And $em is a rather strange name for a repository.  Don't confuse entity manager with entity repository.